# LinearLayout refuses to fill programmaticallycreated LinearLayout wrapper

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to get a linear layout from an XML file to completely fill up the content of another linear layout I've created programmatically but for some reason it will only take up the space it needs (WRAP_CONTENT, as it were).

Here's the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_dayheader_previous"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/leftarrow" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/app_dayheader_title"
    style="@style/titlebar_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_dayheader_next"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/rightarrow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the code. There's a lot of indirection involved for architecture reasons, but basically what happens is this:

A child class inflates the XML file:

```
public class child {

    public View getView(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dayheader, null);
        return layout;
    }
}
```

A parent class that extends LinearLayout calls the child class and adds the result of the call to getView to itself:

```
public class parent extends LinearLayout {
    public parent(Context context) {
        super(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        this.addView(new child().getView(context);
    }
}
```

Finally, another class calls the parent class and adds it to yet another LinearLayout:

```
headerWrapper = new LinearLayout(context);
headerWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
));
headerWrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
headerWrapper.addView(new parent(context));
```

As far as I can tell, all these linear layouts should fill the maximum available width in their respective parents and this is exactly what headerWrapper and the parent class do. However, the linear layout in the XML file (the one returned by child.getView()) does not. Which has me puzzled, as it has exactly the same parameters as the other ones. And yet the only space it takes up is the space it needs rather than filling up its parent.

Does anybody have any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the layout weight of 1 to take effect, you'll need to set the dimension of that axis to 0px. Try this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1f);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, that wasn't it. In fact, the weight in the parent linearlayout wasn't even supposed to be there (I've updated the code to reflect this).

Comment: If you want a child of linear layout to fill available space, you must use weights.